# Pure CSS (no JS) way to determine if multiple checkboxes are checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Using **only** CSS and HTML, I am trying to place content in a span based on whether two or more checkboxes are in a checked (:checked) state.  It's easy enough of course if I only needed to check for one (basically an "OR" situation), but in this case, I effectively need "AND" logic.  Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Why not just use like a line of JS?

Comment: So what's your html, since that's what CSS presents and 'works' on/with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following snippet is supported in modern browsers, according to caniuse.com:

[caniuse.com#search=checked](http://caniuse.com/#search=checked)

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<div data-text="some string"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + input[type=checkbox]:checked + div {
  background: blue;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + input[type=checkbox]:checked + div:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(data-text);
  color: #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ykks37L/1/

Comment: thank you @seemly... wasn't aware that the 2nd 'checked' could be used like that... great..

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps. Remember to accept the answer if it answered your question! =)